# How to solve problem in APK Tools

Tags: applications, file-system, apk, java

I'm trying to decompile an apk with the apk tools and I'm not getting it. When I run `apktool -d myapp.apk` it displays this **error** to me:

```
 Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Invalid chunk type: expected=0x00000200, got=0x00000203
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.checkChunkType(ARSCDecoder.java:542)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTablePackage(ARSCDecoder.java:88)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTableHeader(ARSCDecoder.java:82)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:48)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:786)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:67)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:59)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.getResTable(Androlib.java:66)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.setTargetSdkVersion(ApkDecoder.java:236)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:118)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:170)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Can anyone help me with that? I would offer more reward does not yet

Comment: Known issue with APK Tools: [Issue #2099 Invalid chunk type](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2099)

Comment: Thanks, i resolved with `apktool d -f -r netflix.apk (my apk test).

Comment: @Dakota -f -r may not be the best way. Now, you can build from the latest source.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Apktool v2.5.1-0a7b84-SNAPSHOT to decompile the apk.
This will be fixed in v2.5.1, which is not released yet to the public

here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RmHwBD4DnDHt6RIN1Ua2gHE6F8sPqJ0O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Based on the [comment](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2099#issuecomment-808209673), looks like this will be fixed in v2.5.1, which is not released yet to the public. That said, I got access denied to Google Drive (though, why is it on Google Drive?).

Comment: Hi Andrew - Please check the link again. It should work. It is on google drive as I found it earlier somewhere to decompile an apk , can't locate that place on the internet. I have it on my c://windows location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my powerful tool  Decompiles almost every apk!

https://github.com/kikfox/kikfox

Answer (score 0):

If you might be a bit suspicious of using a jar from

- a not-so-well-known fork of apktool (kikfox) ; or
- a Google Drive link

You may be pleased to know that you can build it yourself rather easily from the official [APKtool github site](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool), following [the easy-to-follow official instructions](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/build/). It just takes a few minutes.

I tried with an apk that had been giving this error.

Using apktool_2.5.0.jar (the most recent release, Dec 2020), from [Apktool release site](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/), the error was seen.

Building apktool from the source, and trying on the same apk, it worked perfectly without the error.